# Node.JS + Socket.io, moving socket event handlers to external module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a server.js file like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    apiRouter = require('./app/routes/api.js'),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    socketEvents = require('./app/modules/socketEvents.js')(io);

//Clears Node Console.
process.stdout.write('\033c');
console.log('Server starting!');

socketEvents.attachEventHandlers();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', apiRouter);
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
    //All requests return single page angular application.
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

mongoose.connect('localhost', 'triviaattack', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('An error occured when connecting to the MongoDB Database');
        throw err;
    }
});

server.listen(1337);
```

And socketEvents.js

```
module.exports = function(io) {

    return {
        attachEventHandlers: function() {

            io.on('connection', function(socket) {

                console.log('client connected');

                socket.on('joinMatchMaking', function(data) {
                    //Every time a player joins the matchmaking queue, check if a game can be created.
                    matchMakingQueue.push(data);
                    var matchedPlayers = [];
                    for (i = 0; i < matchMakingQueue.length; i++) {
                        switch (data.gameType) {
                            case '1v1':
                                matchedPlayers.push(matchMakingQueue[i].username);
                                if (matchedPlayers.length == 2) {
                                    socket.emit('matchFound', {players: matchedPlayers});
                                } 
                                console.log('user joined 1v1 queue');
                            case '2v2':
                                matchedPlayers.push(matchMakingQueue[i].username);
                                if (matchedPlayers.length == 4) {
                                    socket.emit('matchFound', {players: matchedPlayers});
                                } 
                                console.log('user joined 2v2 queue');
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(data.username + ' joined the ' + data.gameType + ' matchmaking queue');
                    console.log('users in queue: ' + matchMakingQueue.length);
                });

                socket.on('leaveMatchMaking', function(username) {
                    matchMakingQueue.splice(matchMakingQueue.indexOf(username), 1);
                    console.log(username + ' left matchmaking queue.');
                    console.log('users in queue: ' + matchMakingQueue.length);
                });

            });

        console.log('events attached');

        }
    }

};
```

When I load my site in my browser, the io.on('connection), function () {...}) event handler is not being called, which should output a console.log message whenever a client connects.  I want to keep my socket.io events outside of my main server.js file because there will be alot of them and I wanted to separate them into their own module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have some socket code in the html file to connect.. can you include it as well?

Comment: Hi, this was my mistake.  Thanks for your response, I was missing the client side code that emitted 'connection', woops :(

Comment: Added this to my index.html  <script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:1337');
  socket.emit('connection');
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

I do this by stuffing all of my socket events in a middleware:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
// listen stuff
var SocketEvents = require('./socket-events.js')(io);
io.use(SocketEvents);
```

... and then in `socket-events.js` something like:

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    return function(socket, next) {
        // do stuff
        return next();
    }
}
```

I should add that in this case the `on("connection")` listener appears not to be necessary, as each middleware function is executed on each incoming socket connection already.

Comment: Hi thanks, what is the advantage of doing it this way vs the way I am trying to?  Just wondering, or if they both achieve the same thing.  Anyways the issue I had was failing to include the client side io.emit('connection')...when I added  <script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:1337');
  socket.emit('connection');
 </script> to my index.html it works

Comment: @David, I like the way this approach lets me further divide functionality. If I needed to split each socket event into its own file, it would be really easy to do so. I've got something similar in a half-completed project I can link you, if you like.

Comment: Sure, I'd like to take a look.  With the approach I did, I would be limited to keeping all of my events in 1 file?

Comment: Oh, no- not at all. I do think it's more concise to use middleware, though. Another benefit is that you can attach additional properties to the socket object and these are then available in successive middleware functions- I don't believe that's the case using modules like the one you've got here. A caveat is that middleware are called in succession, so their order of inclusion is important.

Comment: I love this approach! It makes things very easy for me to follow. You can look at how I've employed it to break apart bits of my logic in the server half of [my project](https://github.com/ConnorWiseman/taka/tree/master/server). Specifically, the middleware directory.

Comment: hey, just saw your response.  Going to check it out later in the day just for educational purposes, thanks!